# How can i change apiurl from angular application?

Tags: android, angular, api, cordova

Im developing an angular mobile app using cordova. I want to change the api-url in the environment file of angular project from the mobile app after building the apk.
The api-url is specified by the user in the application on a text box to connect with their db .How it is possible to change the url?Pls give any solutions

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve]

Comment: please provide code snippets to what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Helloo...
Actually i m converting a software(in angular 5) to app using cordova. We have a number of customers with their own db.Through the app we are reading their url to their db also.Using that, i want to connect them to their database.
I think,for that the url should come in the environment file.How it is possible?